# Getting Apple Mach-O linker

Tags: ios, xcode

This is the error output I am getting when I try to run the project.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_CATransform3DMakeScale", referenced from:
  -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController viewWillAppear:] in AMSlideMenuMainViewController.o
  ___54-[AMSlideMenuMainViewController openLeftMenuAnimated:]_block_invoke in AMSlideMenuMainViewController.o
  ___55-[AMSlideMenuMainViewController openRightMenuAnimated:]_block_invoke in AMSlideMenuMainViewController.o
  ___55-[AMSlideMenuMainViewController closeLeftMenuAnimated:]_block_invoke in AMSlideMenuMainViewController.o
  ___56-[AMSlideMenuMainViewController closeRightMenuAnimated:]_block_invoke in AMSlideMenuMainViewController.o
  -[AMSlideMenuMainViewController configure3DTransformForMenu:panningView:] in AMSlideMenuMainViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
enter code here
```

What does this mean and how can I get rid of it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you include CoreAnimation framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode's warning you that a class called in other classes can't be found in either your custom classes, or the linked frameworks.

As a rule of thumb, every time you include a custom control or module in your project, double check that all its dependencies are included too.

So, in your case, `AMSlideMenuMainViewController` is calling `CATransform3DMakeScale` from CoreAnimation's framework (deduced from `CA` prefix), which is included in **`QuartzCore`**, but it's not included in your project configuration yet.

One way to fix it is to click on your project file, in the summary tab, and add the **QuartzCore** framework to the list of framework.

Then, double-check that the header of QuartzCore is imported where you need it.

For you, I guess in `AMSlideMenuMainViewController`:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> //At the top of your file
```

Then, clean and build and it should be fine!